# Octave Running MPI failed

Tags: mpi, cluster-computing, octave

I'm a new to octave. Now, I run a helloworld example of octave on Ubuntu 14.04, but it always get a failure. The failure information is as below:

```
octave:1> system (" mpirun -x LD_PRELOAD=libmpi.so --hostfile ./hostfile -np 2 octave -q --eval 'pkg load mpi; helloworld ()'");

--------------------------------------------------------------------------
It looks like MPI_INIT failed for some reason; your parallel process is
likely to abort.  There are many reasons that a parallel process can
fail during MPI_INIT; some of which are due to configuration or environment
problems.  This failure appears to be an internal failure; here's some
additional information (which may only be relevant to an Open MPI
developer):

     ompi_mpi_init: ompi_rte_init failed
     --> Returned "(null)" (-43) instead of "Success" (0)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------- 

An error occurred in MPI_Init
on a NULL communicator
MPI_ERRORS_ARE_FATAL (processes in this communicator will now abort,
   and potentially your MPI job)
[computationnode:17991] Local abort before MPI_INIT completed completed 
   successfully, but am not able to aggregate error messages, and not able to 
   guarantee that all other processes were killed!

An error occurred in MPI_Init
on a NULL communicator
MPI_ERRORS_ARE_FATAL (processes in this communicator will now abort,
   and potentially your MPI job)
[computationnode:17992] Local abort before MPI_INIT completed completed
   successfully, but am not able to aggregate error messages, and not able to 
   guarantee that all other processes were killed!

--------------------------------------------------------------------------
It looks like MPI_INIT failed for some reason; your parallel process is
likely to abort.  There are many reasons that a parallel process can
fail during MPI_INIT; some of which are due to configuration or environment
problems.  This failure appears to be an internal failure; here's some
additional information (which may only be relevant to an Open MPI
developer):

     ompi_mpi_init: ompi_rte_init failed
     --> Returned "(null)" (-43) instead of "Success" (0)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

`mpirun` noticed that the job aborted, but has no info as to the process
that caused that situation.

Someone can help me? I desperately want to solve this problem.

Comment: are you sure about your hostfile? have you tried without the `--hostfile` option? have you tried exporting LD_PRELOAD before the `mpirun` command, and just pass `-x LD_PRELOAD` as an option? (the manpage for `mpirun` states that `-x` isn't very sophisticated and it's best to define the env-variable outside the command and only use `-x` to "export" rather than to "define" for mpi's sake). Also, are you sure the `helloworld()` function exists and is accessible from octave in the default path?    (I'm not an mpi expert, this is just general advice)

Comment: Also, you may have better luck with the `parallel` package, it seems better maintained / documented. Especially if you're only looking for _local_ parallelisation.

Comment: Yeap, this problem is solved. It mainly because of the environment variable. Thank you, man. By the way, I'm  new to MPI. In terms of the HOSTFILE, what format and information it should be? Could you give me some examples? For example, I have 2 nodes, one has 4 cores and IP is A.A.A.A  and the other also has 4 cores, IP is B.B.B.B.

Comment: I wouldn't know, like I said I'm not an MPI expert. I just gave my opinion on possible culprits for your problem from general knowledge :)